# Dynamic variables in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, dynamic

I am coding an ore-calculator, and for this I have repeating variables-names like:

```
tritaniumlogo:MineralContainer:new MineralContainer(values)
tritaniumtext:MinText=new MinText(values)
```

The `Mineralcontainer` and the `MinText` are some defined classes. Since I was repeating myself, I tried to re-factor the 80 lines of codes.

So I created an `Array` holding some data with the following code, but it does not work:

```
private var minsVar:Array = [[50, 98, "Tritanium", emptySpace], [50, 134, "Pyerite", emptySpace], [50, 170, "Mexallon", emptySpace], [50, 206, "Isogen", emptySpace], [230, 98, "Noxcium", emptySpace], [230, 134, "Zydrine", emptySpace], [230, 170, "Megacyte", emptySpace], [230, 206, "Morphite", emptySpace]];

for (var a:int = 0; a < minsVar.length; a++) {  
    private var [minsVar[a][2] + "logo"] = new MineralContainer(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], a + 1);
    private var [minsVar[a][2] + "textinput"] = new MinText(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], minsvar[a][2], minsvar[a][3]);
}
```

Comment: Why not create another class that takes those 4 values as parameters in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is inside a class method, Then you may do the following:

```
for (var a:int = 0; a < minsVar.length; a++) {
    this[minsVar[a][2] + "Logo"] = new MineralContainer(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], a + 1);
    this[minsVar[a][2] + "Textinput"] = new MinText(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], minsvar[a][2], minsvar[a][3]);
}
```

Then, you can access them using `this["TritaniumLogo"]` or `this["PyeriteTextinput"]`, for example. However, you are better to store your "new" objects inside some associative arrays:

```
private var minsVar:Array = [[50, 98, "Tritanium", emptySpace], [50, 134, "Pyerite", emptySpace], [50, 170, "Mexallon", emptySpace], [50, 206, "Isogen", emptySpace], [230, 98, "Noxcium", emptySpace], [230, 134, "Zydrine", emptySpace], [230, 170, "Megacyte", emptySpace], [230, 206, "Morphite", emptySpace]];

private var arrLogoes:Array = new Array();
private var arrTextInputs:Array = new Array();
// ...
for (var a:int = 0; a < minsVar.length; a++) {
    arrLogoes[minsVar[a][2]] = new MineralContainer(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], a + 1);
    arrTextInputs[minsVar[a][2]] = new MinText(minsvar[a][0], minsvar[a][1], minsvar[a][2], minsvar[a][3]);
}
```

So that you can access them later using `arrLogoes["Tritanium"]` or `arrTextInputs["Pyerite"]`, for example.